# Active Directory Аутентификация ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Есть десктопная версия приложения, в которой можно авторизоваться через Active Directory. Есть также веб-версия приложения, в которой также должна присутствовать возможность авторизоваться через Active Directory.

Тут возникает вопрос: как мне проверить, совпадают ли введенные мной логин  пароль с логином и паролем пользователя Active Directory?

Comment: Ищите в базе юзера с такими же логином и паролем, если число найденных строк !=0 значит логин и пароль верные.

Comment: Это то да, но только пароли Active Directory пользователей не хранятся в бд

Comment: Для mvc 5 пробовал вот [это](http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/). Думаю, что можно попытаться адаптировать под core

Comment: Я, для похожей задачи, писал специальную сборку и интегрировал ее в SQL Server. Потом просто вызываешь как обычную хранимку в БД. Решение рабочее, но немного геморное, потому что нужные для работы с AD сборки официально не поддерживаются в SQL, но заставить работать вполне можно, правда придется обновлять версии сборок при обновлении версии SQL Server. Если применимо в вашем случае, могу оформить ответ.

Comment: @SlavonDT если не ошибаюсь, .NET Core не поддерживает сборку System.DirectoryServices, так что решение для MVC5 тут вряд ли получится адаптировать

Comment: @Сергей угу, в AD... с логином не проблема, а пароль или, хотя бы, его хэш? ну ну, ищите.